# How can I get my function ceiling(x) to produce a number in the command prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, node-modules

I'm not getting the desired result when I export a function and test it in the command prompt using Node.js. The function contains Math.ceil(x) and it doesn't produce a number when I test it.

I was successful in exporting a function with a message, but I can't seem to do it with Math. I wonder where I am going wrong.

```
//my math.js file:
function ceiling(x){
  return Math.ceil(x);
}
module.exports.ceiling = ceiling;
```

```
//my index.js file
const round = require("./math.js");

round.ceiling(4.9);
/*typing "node index.js" in the command prompt shows blank when I hit enter*/
```

I was expecting to see the output to be 5, but the output is blank

Comment: Your `ceiling()` function *is* producing a result; it's simply not being displayed. Nothing is displayed unless you specifically ask for it. Replace the last line with `console.log(round.ceiling(4.9));`. See the documentation for [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) and the [Console API](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html).

Comment: It's odd that when I replace x with 'message' I don't need to console.log it. I wonder why that is? Thank you for the suggestion by the way, it was very helpful!